# Give an example of a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ such that the image $f(F)$ is not open in $Y$ for a open $F$ in X

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Give an example  of  a  continuous  function  $f : X  \rightarrow Y$ such that the image $f(F)$ is  not open in $Y$ for  a open $F$ in $X$

My attempts  : I know that open map to open,,,here I'm confused  how  can I find  the counter-example

thanks u

Comment: Open need not map to open.  The inverse image of an open is open.

Comment: Try a singleton.

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the usual topology.

Comment: Or a constant function... did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)= \sin(x)$ and choose an open $U=(0, \pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

From Will. M comment  take $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ define by $f(x) = 1$,  as  $f(x) =\{1\}$ which  is closed  as  singleton set is  closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: More importantlyregarding the OP:  $\{1\}$ is not open

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen..exactly  u r right sir